# Selenium Chrome Driver screen size not being set correctly when run from CI

Tags: windows, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

This is a bit hard to describe in a single sentence so I'll have to go into more detail here.

**The Problem:**

I have some Selenium tests and when they run locally, it works perfectly fine.

The issue arises when I run it through **Bamboo** (which itself is running on a **Windows** machine as the **SYSTEM** user due to it being a service), one of the test fails.

After a bit of debugging using `RemoteWebDriver.GetScreenshot()` I discovered that despite setting the screen size to `1920x1080`, it's actually a much smaller `1134x663` causing one of the tests to fail. Locally it respects whatever arbitrary resolution that I set, but on the CI machine with the same Chrome Driver, Selenium version, NUnit and source code it is always this small resolution.

I have work in the future to make the site completely responsive, but at the moment I would still like to ensure that Bamboo uses the size I specify.

**Question:**

Is running a Bamboo through the **SYSTEM** likely to cause any problems for Seleium particularly? It's the only distinction I can see between local and CI running. Are there any other possibilities?

**Other Information:**

How I'm setting screensize

`WebDriver.Window.Size = new Size(Config.WindowWidth, Config.WindowHeight);`

Chrome Driver `Version 29`

NUnit `Version 3.6.1`

Selenium Web Driver `Version 3.4.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked through various options...

---

**Services:**

It seemed initially Bamboo running as a service was sensible. It needs to be permanently on, and 99% of the work doesn't require any sort of graphical interfaces. Except this one case for Selenium.

Since services by default run as SYSTEM, a user which is in "Session 0" - an apparently headless state - I had the thought to enable "Allow service to interact with desktop" in the Services window.

[image: service screenshot]

This didn't work either, however. I read online maybe this was just a legacy option. In any case, it provided the same behaviour as before.

I then thought to create a new "normal" local user to run the service which would run hopefully run under a normal session and not be constrained by any graphical/non-interactive oddities.

[image: alternate user]

Again this didn't work. Bamboo ran fine, and provided a web interface, but Selenium in particular still had the same problems. Unlike with System account, there was no option to "Allow service to interact with desktop".

---

**Scheduled Tasks:**

After this I decided to remove services from the equation altogether and just run Bamboo as a scheduled task for my new local user. I set it to run on PC startup, and run regardless of whether the user was logged in or not.

Still the same behaviour!

I then figured out that if the program was being started without the user already being logged on, it was still "headless" and would give the same issues.

I finally got it working by having the scheduled task run on user logon for this account. Only when the user account actually logged in (and therefore was presented with a normal desktop) would Bamboo be run.

So doing this finally made it work! It also has the advantage that if you're watching via remote desktop you can see the actions take place in real time.

In reflection I can see a couple of pros and cons to this eventual solutions.

---

**Pros:**

- It works...
- I can see Selenium operate in front of my eyes if I remote in

**Cons:**

- It seems like a slight abuse of scheduled tasks. As far as I know, good practice is that things you need to run permanently and in the background, like SQL Server, should be run as a service. Things that run at a certain point but then quit out should be scheduled tasks.
- For this user account, Bamboo shows a shell on the desktop. I've not noticed any slowdown on the site, but I have considered that all the almost continuous output to standard out on the CMD window might impact things. I guess I could wrap the Bamboo program in a batch script and redirect output to null, though.
- The rare times I do have to reboot the server, I will need to log in as this new user to kick off Bamboo.

---

**Summary:**

I hope this helps others, I saw a few other people online with the same issues (even with different CIs/testing tools). My eventual solution might not have even been necessary, I would like to hear other solutions if people do have them. I'd heard possible solutions in using other drivers instead of Chrome, such as PhantomJS, but I really wanted to test it on the true Chrome. I also heard about virtual desktops, but that is just a Linux solution.